# Tika-Python library throws read timeout error for large word document

Tags: python, apache-tika

Trying to parse a word document through tika using Tika-Python library (https://github.com/chrismattmann/tika-python) in python2.7 (I know that it is being depreciated, but few other dependencies work only in python2). But for few of the larger documents I am unable to get the parsed data. I am using the below code snippet to parse the document.

```
headers = {
                "X-Tika-OCRLanguage": "eng",
                'timeout': 300,
                'pool_timeout':  300,
                "X-Tika-OCRTimeout": 300
            }
text_tika = parser.from_file(doc, xmlContent=False, requestOptions={'headers':headers})
```

This code snippet throws following error:

```
ReadTimeout(ReadTimeoutError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=9998): Read timed out. (read timeout=60)",),)
```

Tried various request options to increase the read timeout but failed. Can anybody please help here?

Comment: If you run the Tika Server manually, and send the troublesome word document to the server by hand, how long does it take to get a response?

Comment: @Gagravarr When I try the to make a curl request directly the response time is somewhere around 50sec.
`* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
49.856982s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, thanks to the repository owner @chrismattmann who pointed out that the timeout parameter should be outside the header parameter. The above code should look like this to work:

```
headers = {
            "X-Tika-OCRLanguage": "eng",
            "X-Tika-OCRTimeout": "300"
        }
text_tika = parser.from_file(doc, xmlContent=False, requestOptions={'headers': headers, 'timeout': 300})
```

Comment: This was the case encountered by me when I parsing pdf and image files using Tika in standalone server mode with OCR enabled. It worked flawlessly for 99% of the files tested earlier after adding the headers like the following it stopped working for all files

returned value is {'metadata': None, 'content': None, 'status': 400}

If I remove the headers from requestOptions it is working for 99% files

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting timeout as advised in @CryptoRex answer, but received a warning, after which the parsing aborted:

```
 WARNING: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: X-Tika-OCRTimeout is an invalid X-Tika-OCR header
```

Same with lowercase (`OCRtimeout`), so it might be that this header no longer supported.

What worked for me, is enabling OCR auto strategy:

```
"X-Tika-PDFocrStrategy": "auto"
```